# pandas str.extractall find unknown number of groups / regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

After some searching I seem to be coming up a bit blank. I'm also a total regex simpleton...

I have a csv file with data like this:

```
header1   header2
row1      "asdf (qwer) asdf"
row2      "asdf (hghg) asdf (lkjh)"
row3      "asdf (poiu) mkij (vbnc) yuwuiw (hjgk)"
```

I've put double quotes around the rows in header2 for clarity that it is one field.

I want to extract each occurrence of words between brackets (). There will be a least one occurrence per row, but I don't know ahead of time how many occurrences of bracketed words will appear in each line.

Using the wonderful https://www.regextester.com/ i think the regex i need is `\(.*?\)`

But I keep getting:

`ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups`

the code i used was:

`pattern = r'\(.*?\)'
extracted = df.loc[:, 'header2'].str.extractall(pattern)`

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You're so close.. you'll kick yourself. Try `'(\(.*?\))'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a capture group inside the parenthesis.  Also, when using `extractall`, I'd use `unstack` so it matches the structure of your DataFrame:

```
df.header2.str.extractall(r'\((.*?)\)').unstack()
```

```
          0
match     0     1     2
0      qwer   NaN   NaN
1      hghg  lkjh   NaN
2      poiu  vbnc  hjgk
```

If you're concerned about performance, don't use `pandas` string operations:

```
pd.DataFrame([re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', row) for row in df.header2])
```

```
     0     1     2
0  qwer  None  None
1  hghg  lkjh  None
2  poiu  vbnc  hjgk
```

Comment: Perhaps use `\(([^)]+)\)` instead, more efficient than the `.*?` combo.